# Facebook API for extracting basic(Public) profile info of a person

Tags: facebook, api, profile, public

Actually I want to extract basic(Public Profile) information of a person on Facebook by it's name or email-ID without any type of authentication. So, can anyone tell me the detailed procedure how i can acheive this using Java Programming and i want the result in XML format

Answer (score 2):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/4
```

Will give you a result similar to -

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

That will give you all the public information about a user.  The response you get is a JSON object.  If you want it in XML you'll have to manually convert it.

**Beaware that not all USER_ID's will return information.  It all depends on the user's privacy settings.**

---

I have no knowledge of JAVA so I can't give you and code samples, but you can make a simple HTTP request to that URL using whatever methods you feel comfortable with...